# Oracle Managed Data Access The underlying provider failed on Open

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

In my C# console app using `.Net 4.6.1` and `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` and `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework` i get an error in the following code. The code works the first 74 times, then fails with the error:

> The underlying provider failed on Open

```
THING tempThing = thingEntity.THINGS
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(d => d.THING_ID == thi)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I've ruled out a data error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred when switching from the Oracle.DataAccess driver to the managed driver.

As a Q&D fix, I found that I can increase the Max Pool Size in the connection string. This worked for now, but the real answer is to handle disposing of the connections better.

Max Pool Size=200;